# Подставить подмассивы в регулярных выражениях

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть такой код:

```
var arr = [["а", "б", "В"], ["г", "Д","е"], ["ж", "з","и"]];

"Текст1 ТЕКСТ2 текст3".replace(/текст/gi,function($0){return $0 +" "+ arr});
```

Получается ответ:

```
Текст а,б,В,г,Д,е,ж,з,и1 ТЕКСТ а,б,В,г,Д,е,ж,з,и2 текст а,б,В,г,Д,е,ж,з,и3
```

Как переделать код так, чтобы получить такой ответ:

```
Текст а,б,В1 ТЕКСТ г,Д,е2 текст ж,з,и3
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const arr = [["а", "б", "В"], ["г", "Д","е"], ["ж", "з","и"]];
const iter = arr.values();
console.log("Текст1 ТЕКСТ2 текст3".replace(/текст/gi,function($0){return $0 +" "+ iter.next().value.join()}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно завести обычный счетчик и с каждым вызовом replace увеличивать его...

```js
let arr = [["а", "б", "В"], ["г", "Д","е"], ["ж", "з","и"]];
let str = "Текст1 ТЕКСТ2 текст3";

let i = 0;
str = str.replace(/текст/gi, function($0) {
  return $0 + " " + arr[ i++ ];
});

// str = str.replace( /текст/gi, ($0) => $0 + " " + arr[ i++ ] );

console.log(str);
```

Если функция будет длиннее, хорошо бы выбрать более осмысленное слово вместо `i`